# ActionScript 3.0 import swf

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

i've little bit trouble with imported swf. Problem is that imported swf has movie clip which exported as movie clip class. Code is here:
Imported swf:

```
 class myBooks(){

    var myBg:MovieClip = new backGround();
    stage.addChild(myObjects);
```

and HOLDER flash file:

```
    var txt:String = "Project/book2.swf";
    var myLoader:Loader = new Loader();
    var url:URLRequest = new URLRequest(txt); 
    myLoader.load(url); 
    addChild(myLoader);
```

when i try to run , it shows me error like this:

```
   TypeError: Error #1009 cannot access a property or method of a null object reference at actions::myBooks()
```

Comment: var myBg:MovieClip = new backGround();
          stage.addChild(myBg);

Comment: problem was with stage.addChild();  when i remove stage and just type addChild(myBg) it works perfect. why?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
class myBooks()
{
    public function myBooks():void
    {
        if(stage)
        {
            init(null);
        }
        else
        {
            addEventListener( Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE,init)
        }
    }
    private function init( e:Event = null )
    {
         var myBg:MovieClip = new backGround();
         stage.addChild(myObjects);
    }
}
```

Hope that help